# Azure Table batch insert from Java Using SAS fails

Tags: java, azure

Trying to use a batch insert to azure table fails if using a SAS ("Shared access signature"). 
When using account key (which is less secure I guess) it works.

Example code:

```
StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature credentials = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature("sig=.....");

CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(new URI("https://<storage account>.table.core.windows.net/<tablename>"), credentials);

CloudTable cloudTable = cloudTableClient.getTableReference("<tablename>");

//these 2 will be in a batch
TableServiceEntity d1 = new TableServiceEntity("3333333333333", "22222222222222" + System.currentTimeMillis());
TableServiceEntity d2 = new TableServiceEntity("3333333333333", "eeeeeeeeeee" + System.currentTimeMillis());

//single
TableServiceEntity d3 = new TableServiceEntity("ddddddddddddddddddd", "dddddddddd" + System.currentTimeMillis());

//prepare batch
TableBatchOperation batch = new TableBatchOperation();
batch.insert(d1);
batch.insert(d2);
try {
        // this will work (not batch, just to show that regular insert works)
        cloudTable.execute(TableOperation.insert(d3));

        // this will fail
        cloudTable.execute(batch);

} catch (StorageException e) {
            //here we get "Unsupported Media Type" (415 error)
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
}
System.out.println("OK");
```

The error I get is:

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Unsupported Media Type
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:315)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableBatchOperation.execute(TableBatchOperation.java:418)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:475)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:432)
    at com.bgprotect.azurestorage.Test.main(Test.java:49)
```

SAS

```
sig=<sig>&se=2020-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sv=2015-04-05&tn=<table name>&sp=raud
```

Comment: Please share your SAS token and also the detailed error message.

Comment: added the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the issue on [`Github`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/584), please try to change the following line of code:

```
CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(new URI("https://<storage account>.table.core.windows.net/<tablename>"), credentials);
```

to:

```
CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(new URI("https://<storage account>.table.core.windows.net"), credentials);
```

Essentially don't include the name of the table in the URI. It should only be `https://account-name.table.core.windows.net`.

P.S. I didn't realize you had also opened an issue on [`Github`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/249) regarding this :).